# Issues runnig kernel 6.0.1

Tags: boot, kernel, initramfs, initrd

I have issues when booting the kernel 6.0.1, here the things :
I can compile the kernel, but when making update-initramfs -u (for update or -c to create) -k 6.0.1, the initramfs-tools scripts :

```
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/ORDER ignored: not executable
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-bottom/ORDER ignored: not executable
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/panic/ORDER ignored: not executable
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top/ORDER ignored: not executable
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount/ORDER ignored: not executable
```

But it make it throught anyway.
Grub is correctly updated.
After reboot, the system correctly boot on the new kernel, but have an issue : kernel couldn't find suitable memory target.
So I think that is a initramfs issue.
After that, I notice that my new kernel image is far more bigger that the olds ones :

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   16 oct.  15 11:33 initrd.img -> initrd.img-6.0.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  61M sept. 15 18:25 initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  61M sept. 15 18:24 initrd.img-5.15.0-47-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  61M sept. 29 18:52 initrd.img-5.15.0-48-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  61M oct.  12 21:21 initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 482M oct.  16 15:06 initrd.img-6.0.1
```

So I reduced it with :

```
root@laptop:/lib/modules/6.0.1# find . -name *.ko -exec strip --strip-unneeded {} *
```

The image size was similar to others versions' images, and made a update-initramfs.
After that, no more memory issue, the kernel ran, but failed to load modules, and entered into rescue mod. The loading-module.service was unable to start, failed because of some rights reasons, if I correctly understood..

If someone had once the same problem, or an idea to fix that, I'll appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: Can not find anything that says you can use 6.0.1 only 6.0 so maybe that one is not ready for Ubuntu?

Comment: Why are you compiling a kernel if you can't do it properly, You an install already compiled mainline kernels easily.

Comment: When running a mainline kernel, you're turning your Ubuntu machine into a testing platform. And if you're compiling the kernel yourself, you're experimenting even more. See the below thread for an easy solution to install mainline kernels.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add the mainline kernel PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160535/how-do-i-add-the-mainline-kernel-ppa)

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414115/initrd-img-of-linux-5-4-174-in-ubuntu-20-04-is-larger-than-900mb) help?

Comment: @ArturMeinild The PPA mentioned in the highest voted answer in the question "How do I add the mainline kernel PPA?" does not exist anymore.

Comment: Then maybe the answer could use an update...

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your returns.
It turns out that it was the lockdown kernel parameter (when configure with make menuconfig), I set it to integrity mode, for increasing security. But it seems that parameter didn't allow the kernel to charge the modules ! It sounds strange, but I turned off the lockdown kernel, re compiled and reinstalled it, now it's work perfectly. Too bad for this security parameter.

```
# uname -r
6.0.1
```

@Artur Meinild, @Doug Smythies : Thanks again for the help, I explored yours suggestions too.